# "What is the difference" or "what are the differences"?

Tags: difference

I was used to use *"What are the difference between _____ and _____"*, but when I accidentally typed *"What is"* on English StackExchange asking question, it shows up *"What is the difference between _____ and _____"* too!

Then, I became bewildered which word is most appropriate in the situation that I do not know whether there will be multiple differences **or** only one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both "What is the difference between X and Y?" and "What are the differences between X and Y?" are grammatical and will be understood.

According to my native-speaker intuition, "What is the difference ...?" is the normal phrasing.  I would only use "What *are* the *differences* ...?" if I was already pretty sure that there was *more than one* difference.

---

**EDIT:** Some additional cases that came up in the comments:

- The *labels* "X" and "Y" will, of course, always be different, but that does not count as a difference between the *things* X and Y, and therefore is not a reason to use the plural form.  The answer to "What is/are the difference/s between ice cream and ice-cream?" would be "There is none, they are the same thing."<sup>1</sup>
- *"What is **a** difference between X and Y?"* is also grammatical, but it means something that one hardly ever wants to say: the speaker has *deliberately refused to indicate* how many differences he or she thinks there are, and no matter how many the *listener* thinks there are, the speaker only wants to hear about one of them.  The only time I personally would use this variation is if I was writing an exam question.
- *"How do X and Y differ?"* is an alternative phrasing that avoids the question of number altogether; unlike *"What is **a** difference..."*, it carries no special connotations.

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider also [tomAYto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ3fjQa5Hls#t=61s) versus [tomAHto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2oEmPP5dTM).  You might find it helpful to read up on the [use-mention distinction](http://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/use_and_mention.htm).

Comment: *"What is a difference..."* also grammatically correct right? | So is it true to use *is a* for insisted 1 difference, *is the* for 1 or all difference **and** *are the* for insisted multiple differences?

Comment: "What is *a* difference" is grammatical, yes, but it's almost never what you want to say.  It means: you are *refusing to indicate* how many differences you think there are, and regardless of how many there really are, you only want to be told about one of them, respondent's choice.  The only situation I can think of, right now, where this would be the desired form is if you're writing exam questions.

Comment: (I should probably add: Native speakers of English know very well that the choice among *a*, *the*, and no article is one of the hardest aspects of the language for non-native speakers to get 100%, and will cut you lots of slack.)

Comment: But if you wanted to leave number totally unspecified you might ask, "How do X and Y differ?"

Comment: I've thought of something else! *"What are the differences between X and Y?"* is more correct since their 1st difference would be their name/object type/characteristic! If I ask "What is the difference between X (ice cream) and Y (ice-cream)?", you could reply me that X has no hyphen while Y has.

Comment: @Jim Nice, but I can't remember the last time I heard someone say it that way.

Comment: @XPMai I'm sorry, that is not more correct: the difference between the *labels* "X" and "Y" does not count.  See edit.

Comment: @XPMai Unrelatedly, FYI, AmEng requires one to say "you could reply that ..." with no "me" in there.  (I can say "reply *to* me" but not with a "that"-clause following.)

Comment: @zwol, what I tried to convey was my idea, so I didn't bother the grammar. Just to confirm, did you mean I was supposed to say *"you could reply to me..."* but not *"you could reply me..."*?

Comment: @XPMai You should just say "you could reply that ...".  No *to*, no *me*.